# I am trying to download React js, but I am getting this error again and again?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am downloading react js with npm , but I am getting this error again and again. Can any give me solution.I have tried multiple times but it is still giving me same error.

C:\react\todo>npm start

```
> todo@0.1.0 start C:\react\todo
> react-scripts start
Starting the development server...

events.js:180
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:3000/' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todo@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the todo@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HAROON & ABDULREHMAN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-28T21_27_54_711Z-debug.log
```

Comment: what does the error log say?  `C:\Users\HAROON & ABDULREHMAN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-28T21_27_54_711Z-debug.log`

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found this.

I(tylerlaberge) ran into this exact issue as well and found that it is only present with react-scripts@3.0.0, downgrading to react-scripts@2.1.8 resolved the issue without needing to mess with environment variables.

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6985#issuecomment-490319841

Answer (score 0):

You should use `npx create-react-app appname` this is from react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html. I use to have a lot of problems when I used `npm create-react-app`, they all went away when I stated using npx.